# inline styling a label in haml

Tags: ruby, haml

My label has a margin-bottom set in the main custom.css file

On this one particular label, I'd like to remove the margin-bottom by using inline styling. I can't seem to work out where to put the styling (or how). The margin bottom is in the '.field label'

```
 .field.checkbox_owners_field{:style => "padding-bottom:0;"}
      = owner_fields.input :terms, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline,
                            label: "Agree to #{link_to 'supplier terms', supplier_terms_path, style: 'color: #E62B8A', target: '_blank'} and #{link_to 'privacy policy', privacy_path, style: 'color: #E62B8A', target: '_blank'}".html_safe,
                            required: true
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to override the `margin-bottom` value for this label? Try setting it to 0 in the inline styles: `.field.checkbox_owners_field{:style => "padding-bottom:0;margin-bottom:0;"}`.

Comment: thanks but if I do that the label itself still has margin-bottom

Comment: What if you change this line: `label: "Agree to #{link_to 'supplier terms', supplier_terms_path, style: 'color: #E62B8A;margin-bottom:0', target: '_blank'} and #{link_to 'privacy policy', privacy_path, style: 'color: #E62B8A', target: '_blank'}".html_safe`

Comment: debug at first the css in the firebug/chrom-inspector to make valid css code

Comment: thanks Nicolay. It still has a margin-bottom even after changes the css as you suggest.

Comment: Can you give examples of the html you are currently getting and what you want to get?